# CodeIgniter Error: Trying to get property of non-object when querying a database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'am not sure why it happens, because when I'am using the same model function in another controller, it works perfectly, but not in this controller.

While submitting a `<form method="POST"/>`, i'am doing some checking in my controller to auto assign ordering value before inserting an item into DB.

`controllers/content.php`:

```
class Content extends Backend_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->activeComponent = 1;
    }
    // FUNCTIONS BEFORE
    public function form($id = FALSE){
        // Some another $item['fields'] gathered from $this->input->post('form_fields');
        $item['catid']      = $this->input->post('form_catid');     // Actually it = 5
        $item['ordering']   = $this->input->post('form_ordering');  // Actually it = '' (empty string)
        // Auto-ordering
        if($item['ordering'] == ''){
            $item['ordering'] = $this->categories_model->auto_ordering($this->activeComponent, $item['catid']);
            return var_dump($item); // DEBUG4
        }
    }
    // FUNCTIONS AFTER
}
```

And here is my modal doing a check `/core/MY_Model.php`:

```
// My base model shared with each custom models
class MY_Model extends CI_Model{
    protected   $_table_name        = '';

    public function auto_ordering($component, $level){

        var_dump('Component: '. $component); // DEBUG1
        var_dump('Level: '. $level); // DEBUG2

        $this->_table_name = 'categories';

        // Get know the last item in a set with the highest ORDERING value
        $ordering = $this->db
            ->select('ordering')
            ->where('cid', $component)
            ->where('pid', $level)
            ->order_by('ordering DESC')
            ->get($this->_table_name)
            ->row();

        var_dump($this->db->last_query()); // DEBUG3

        $last_order = intval($ordering->ordering);

        // Increase by 1
        return ++$last_order;
    }
}
```

I was using the same check method while adding a new record for the "categories" and not the "content". I don't why I can't retrieve the values. When doing a `var_dump($ordering);` in `/core/MY_Model.php`, i'am getting an empty array. Anyone see something wrong here ?

**==== UPDATED ====**

I've added some debug infos to the code as recommended by @SuthanBala, so here is a dump:

```
// DEBUG1
string 'Component: 1' (length=12)

// DEBUG2
string 'Level: 5' (length=8)

// DEBUG3
string 'SELECT `ordering`
FROM (`cis_categories`)
WHERE `cid` =  '1'
AND `pid` =  '5'
ORDER BY `ordering` DESC' (length=102)

// ERROR
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: core/MY_Model.php
Line Number: 197

// DEBUG4
array (size=10)
    'catid' => string '5' (length=1)
    'rid' => int 0
    'alvl' => string '10' (length=2)
    'ordering' => int 1
    'state' => string '0' (length=1)
    'title' => string 'article3' (length=8)
    'slug' => string 'article3' (length=8)
    'text' => string '<p>sad</p>' (length=10)
    'aid' => string '1' (length=1)
    'pubdate' => string '2013-12-04' (length=10)
```

**==== UPDATED 2 ====**

And that is a dump from another `controllers/categories.php` where it works perfectly:

```
// DEBUG1
string 'Component: 1' (length=12)

// DEBUG2
string 'Level: 2' (length=8)

// DEBUG3
string 'SELECT `ordering`
FROM (`cis_categories`)
WHERE `cid` =  '1'
AND `pid` =  '2'
ORDER BY `ordering` DESC' (length=102)

array (size=7)
  'cid' => string '1' (length=1)        // $component
  'pid' => string '2' (length=1)        // $level
  'title' => string 'Article 5th' (length=11)
  'slug' => string 'article-5th' (length=11)
  'image' => string 'no-image.jpg' (length=12)
  'description' => string '<p>This should be automatically ordered to the 5th position.</p>' (length=64)
  'ordering' => int 5
```

Comment: are you dumping $ordering inside the function?

Comment: @Edward - yes, in `function auto_ordering($component, $level){}` just right before the `$last_order = intval(...)`.

Comment: Is the problem resolved? If not, here are a few things that might help debug. It appears that the db is retrieving no entry, and that error get produced when you do the `row()` on an empty results. So start off by doing this var_dump `var_dump($compontent, $level)` above the query, and `$this->db->last_query()` below the query. And paste the code here so it would help us understand a few things

Comment: @ISuthanBala thanks for suggestions, i made a modification to my question, please check that again to the dumps

Comment: What is the array at DEBUG4 ?

Comment: That's an array of item which should be used for inserting a record into the db with `$this->content_model->save($item);`

Comment: I see that you mentioned that you got this function working when called from another controller. Can you dump the result array of that and update the question please.

Comment: It is not doing the same query here? It is doing a query where `cid = 1` and `pid = 2` but in our original case we tried `cid = 1` and `pid = 5`. Perhaps you can run the query from DEBUG3 from UPDATE1 on a `PHPMYADMIN` and see if it returns any results?

Comment: You were right, there was a problem in that query, the problem is that I can't use the same query in both different controllers with their different database schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the model in controller.

```
$this->load->model('categories_model');
```

Add the above line into the `_construct()` in content.php

Comment: He would have gotten another error in that case, that's not the issue

Comment: I want to remark an attention that I have exactly the same check inside another controller which works perfectly.

Comment: You are trying to retrieve ordering from the $ordering array. But in this case the $ordering array is empty. Thats why the error was occured. You need to check the array is empty or not before using $ordering->ordering

Comment: In my case it's not empty, but i know what you've ment, I already checked that before, but that wasn't an issue